# Refresh page to update link active status based on window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I'm starting to learn ReactJS and I have created a small app with 3 screens: home, about & users. I am using bootstrap for styles.

I have the following logic `active={window.location.pathname === "/about"}` for each link to pass in a boolean to determine if it the active page or not.

When I click the links it loads the page I need however the style doesn't update to reflect that the link is active however if I refresh the page it updates the style.

From what I've read online I can do something with states to reload the page to update the style etc but I'm not sure how to actually implement this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';

import Navigation from './components/navigation';

import Home from './views/home';
import Users from './views/users';
import About from './views/about';

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Navigation></Navigation>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/about"><About /></Route>
            <Route path="/users"><Users /></Route>
            <Route path="/"><Home /></Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';

import NavigationItem from './navigationItem';

export default class Navigation extends Component {

    render(){
        return( 
            <div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                                <NavigationItem active={window.location.pathname === "/"} path="/" content="Home"></NavigationItem>
                                <NavigationItem active={window.location.pathname === "/about"} path="/about" content="About"></NavigationItem>
                                <NavigationItem active={window.location.pathname === "/users"} path="/users" content="Users"></NavigationItem>    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>     
        );
    }
}
```

#### NavigationItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class NavigationItem extends Component {
    render(){
        if(this.props.active){
            return(
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link active" to={this.props.path}>{this.props.content}</Link>
                </li> 
            );
        } else {
            return(
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <Link class="nav-link" to={this.props.path}>{this.props.content}</Link>
                </li> 
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another React Router component called `NavLink` that has an [`activeClassName`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) attribute that you may find useful.

I use it like this:

```
<li>
  <NavLink
    activeClassName={styles.active}
    to="/path"
  >Route path
  </NavLink>
</li>
```

where `active` is the class I bring in from my CSS module.

Comment: I would complement this with: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink
since "activeStyle" and "isActive" could also be an option

Comment: That's brill thanks, I've replaced `<Link class="nav-link" to={this.props.path}>{this.props.content}</Link>` with `<NavLink exact activeClassName="nav-link active" className="nav-link" to={this.props.path}>{this.props.content}</NavLink>` and removed the logic and that works perfectly, thank you.